# Cocos2D 2.0 - changing the rect of a CCSprite / stretching a sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have created an atlas with all images I will use in a class. If this was a sprite created from an image, I would create it like

```
mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"white.png" rect:frame];
```

"white.png" is a 1x1 pixel image that I am stretching to cover the entire CCSprite size, that is defined by rect:frame on that API.

But in order to optimize I/O and memory, I put white.png in an atlas and my idea was to create it using

```
mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"white.png"];
```

but this will create a 1x1 pixel sprite. So, my idea was to create a category to extend CCSprite with these lines

```
@implementation CCSprite (CCSprite_Resize)


-(void)resizeTo:(CGSize) theSize
{
    CGFloat newWidth = theSize.width;
    CGFloat newHeight = theSize.height;


    float startWidth = self.contentSize.width;
    float startHeight = self.contentSize.height;

    float newScaleX = newWidth/startWidth;
    float newScaleY = newHeight/startHeight;

    self.scaleX = newScaleX;
    self.scaleY = newScaleY;

}
```

so I could do this

```
mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"white.png"];
[mySprite resizeTo:frame.size];
```

and the 1x1 sprite would be stretched to cover the size I want.

The problem is that this is not working.

any clues? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in your case you can use CCLayerColor to create one-color layer. There is no need to use sprite for it.

About your question - make sure, that frame.size is not zero (CGSizeZero)

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I have to do it with CCSprite because the the whole thing comes from a CCSprite derived class that has to be a sprite. The size is not zero.

Comment: and mySprite after initialization with spriteFrame is not nil?

Comment: no, but the sprite is still 1x1 pixel. Can this be a bug? (not scaling sprites from the frame cache?)

Comment: just had checked in a real project. added your category with resize method and call it. works fine. check if some needed variables are nil. by the way, check actual frame.size value in the debugger

Comment: this is very strange. There's nothing nil. Size is not zero and it is still 1x1. I will double check that.

Answer (score 2):

Make shore you are not overriding somthing like `- (CGAffineTransform)nodeToParentTransform`. I'm using Box2d physics with cocos2d, and provided be template class PhysicsSprite (subclass of CCSprite) overrided it, and there was a bug: scale property didn't change anything. I fixed it like this:

```
- (CGAffineTransform)nodeToParentTransform
{
    b2Vec2 pos = body_->GetPosition();

    float x = pos.x * PTM_RATIO;
    float y = pos.y * PTM_RATIO;

    // Make matrix
    float radians = body_->GetAngle();
    float c = cosf(radians);
    float s = sinf(radians);

    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(anchorPointInPoints_, CGPointZero))
    {
        x += c * -anchorPointInPoints_.x * scaleX_ + -s * -anchorPointInPoints_.y * scaleY_;
        y += s * -anchorPointInPoints_.x * scaleX_ + c * -anchorPointInPoints_.y * scaleY_;
    }

    // Rot, Translate Matrix
    transform_ = CGAffineTransformMake( c * scaleX_, s * scaleX_,
    -s * scaleY_, c * scaleY_,
    x, y );

    return transform_;
}
```

In original, there was no `scaleX_` and `scaleY_` multiplying.

Comment: thanks, but what I am supposed to do with this? Put it on a class? extend a class?

Comment: This is just what happand to my CCSPrite, so it didn't sclaed.I didn't see all your code, so supposed you cuold do something same, and posted my exaple. If you only added your `resizeTo:` method, my solution will not help you.